# Keep multiple IP address settings for one ethernet controller (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a laptop that often gets access to internet in two places:

- For one place, I need to obtain the IP address automatically
- but for the other place, a static IP address and DNS server should be used.

The problem is windows 7 doesn't keep the settings when you choose to "obtain an IP address automatically", so every time I have to fill in the same settings when switching to the static assigned ones.

I'm fine with switching IP address settings with few clicks or commands,
but it seems pretty annoying I have to fill in all details every time.

Is there a built-in feature that I can use or any 3rd party solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I can help with that! =)
Here's my bat file code that i run regularly. Tell me what u want and i can customize the netsh part =)

This is a windows only solution and just requires you to copy paste code into a txt file and change the ".txt" part (show extensions must be enabled in view) to ".bat"

```
@echo off
REM <-- Old way of commenting "REM"

REM Here we get admin privileges
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

REM Here we set all the interfaces
REM Run ipconfig in cmd to get your interface names =)

REM here we set DNS
netsh interface show interface
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=8.8.8.8 index=1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Local Area Connection* 4" address=8.8.8.8 index=1
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Ethernet" address=8.8.4.4 index=2
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver "Local Area Connection* 4" address=8.8.4.4 index=2


pause
```